# how to get the beginning, end, and duration of a TDengine window query?

Tags: window, tdengine

Is there any keywords or pseudocolumns  that can indicate  the beginning, end, and duration of a TDengine window query?

I am using partitioned queries and windowed queries of TDengine,, as shown below:
`Select max (current) from meters partition by location interval (10m)`
But this query does not return the start time of the window.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are finding is _WSTART, _WEND, and _WDURATION.